# List of all muted members (timeout)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to have a way to have the list of all the members who are timeout with their remaining timeout, do you have an idea?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you edit the question and [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and share the code of what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be very taxing depending on how big your server is. But you will have to loop through all members like so:

```js
secToTime = function(n) {
    let ms = n % 1000;
    let s = Math.floor((n / 1000) % 60).toString().padStart(2, `0`);
    let m = Math.floor((n / (60 * 1000)) % 60).toString().padStart(2, `0`);
    let h = Math.floor((n / (3600 * 1000)) % 3600).toString().padStart(2, `0`);
    return `${h}:${m}:${s}.${ms}`;
}

let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(`your_guild_id`); // Or some other method if you choose
let guildMembers = guild.members.cache;
let timeOutEnding = member.communicationDisabledUntilTimestamp;
let now = new Date().getTime();
let list = ``;

guildMembers.forEach(member => {
    if(timeOutEnding > now){
        let remaining = secToTime(Math.round(timeOutEnding - now));

        list += `Member: <@${member.id}> ~ Remaining Time: ${remaining}\n`;
    }
});
```

Then do something with that information:

```js
// if done via slash command:
await interaction.reply({
    content: list || `No members currently in time out.`,
});

// if done via message command:
await message.reply({
    content: list || `No members currently in time out.`,
});
```

Example response: Member: @MemberName ~ Remaining Time: 00:51:32.506